# Wall Removal - Not Load Bearing - Keep Ceiling Joists

Tags: walls, ceiling, joists, removal

DIYer here and recently bought a fixer upper. I'd like to remove the wall between the kitchen and the livingroom. I'd like to complete this project soon so I can insulate the attic. My home inspector told me that wall is not load bearing and I can remove it if I want. The kitchen and livingroom each measure 12'x17'. There is no plumbing inside the wall separating the rooms but there is electrical. I'm very comfortable with electricity, so I have no issues relocating it. How can I remove this wall while keeping the ceiling joists?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Attic]

Here's the wall and you can see the load bearing beam 
[image: Seperation Wall]

Comment: The wall you want to remove is on the left of your second picture? Where those joists come together in the attic is over top the beam?

Comment: If all those joists splice over the wall, the wall *is* load-bearing. You'll need a suitably sized beam (either flush or descending). If that's not the case, the question isn't clear.

Comment: What wall are you trying to remove in the second photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  If the joists overlap, than it's load bearing.  Take that wall out, and the ceiling will collapse inward.  That being said, it's really only supporting the ceiling load, not a full structural load.  But, you can't take it out without replacing it.

Long Answer:  2 Part blog I wrote for exactly this scenario.  Part 2 deals with the structural bits.  http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/kitchen-renovation-moving-to-open-concept/

Hire an engineer and get a permit.  It'll stop the insurance company from cancelling, and the city from shutting you down.

Also, find a new home inspector.

Comment: I think the joists overlap at the beam or that is how I read the question.

Comment: Precisely.  And if you remove the support, it will fall.

Comment: We don't know if the beam is clear span , the wall could still be removed except for cripples if there supporting the beam.